# Bluecove: SERVICE_SEARCH_DEVICE_NOT_REACHABLE issue

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I try to connect to a custom Bluetooth device using BlueCove. I can pair the device, but when I try to search for services I always get SERVICE_SEARCH_DEVICE_NOT_REACHABLE in serviceSearchCompleted() and no services are discovered. If I try the same thing outside Java (in Windows), the PC bluetooth device discovers and can connect (using COM21, COM22, ...) to the SPP service on my device.

What am I doing wrong?
I also tried to do the service search after the device discovery is ended. Same issue.
Please find below my code.

Many thanks in advance for any idea on how to solve this,

Adrian.

```
public class Test {
        private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName());

        private static final String NAME = "XXXX";
        private static final String PIN = "1234";
        private static final UUID[] UUIDS = new UUID[] {new UUID(0x0003), new UUID(0x1101)};

        private LocalDevice localDevice;
        private DiscoveryAgent discoveryAgent;
        private DiscoveryListener discoveryListener = new GDiscoveryListener();
        private Map<Integer, RemoteDevice> searchForServices = new HashMap<Integer, RemoteDevice>();
        private Collection<ServiceRecord> servicesDiscovered = new HashSet<ServiceRecord>();
        private Object lock = new Object();
        private CountDownLatch waitForDevices;

        protected void connect() {
                try {
                        localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
                        localDevice.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);
                        LOG.info("Local Device: " + localDevice.getFriendlyName()
                                        + "(" + localDevice.getBluetoothAddress() + ")");
                        discoveryAgent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();
                        LOG.finest("Start discovering devices");
                        discoveryAgent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, discoveryListener);
                try {
                    synchronized(lock) {
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                                if (searchForServices.size() > 0) {
                                        waitForDevices = new CountDownLatch(searchForServices.size());
                                waitForDevices.await();
                                }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Error waiting to terminate discovery", e);
                }
                LOG.finest(servicesDiscovered.size() + " services discovered");
                LOG.finest("Device discovery completed");
                } catch (BluetoothStateException e) {
                        LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Error initializing Bluetooth", e);
                }

        }

        private class GDiscoveryListener implements DiscoveryListener {

                public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice rd, DeviceClass dc) {
                        try {
                                String name = rd.getFriendlyName(false);
                                boolean isMine = NAME.equals(name);
                                LOG.info("Discovered: " + name + "(" + rd.getBluetoothAddress() + ")"
                                                + (isMine ? "" : " - ignoring"));
                                if (!isMine)
                                        return;
                                if (!rd.isAuthenticated()) {
                                        LOG.finest("Try to pair with " + name
+ " PIN: " + PIN);
                                        boolean paired = RemoteDeviceHelper.authenticate(rd, PIN);
                                        LOG.info("Pair with " + name + (paired ? " succesfull" : " failed"));
                                }
                                int transID = discoveryAgent.searchServices(null, UUIDS, rd, discoveryListener);
                                searchForServices.put(transID, rd);
                                LOG.finest("Searching for services for " + name + " with transaction " + transID);
                        } catch (BluetoothStateException e) {
                                LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Cannot search services for "
                                                + rd.getBluetoothAddress(), e);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Error connecting ", e);
                        } catch (Throwable t) {
                                LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Cannot search services for "
                                                + rd.getBluetoothAddress(), t);
                        }
                }

                public void inquiryCompleted(int respCode) {
                        synchronized(lock) {
                    lock.notify();
                }

                switch (respCode) {
                    case DiscoveryListener.INQUIRY_COMPLETED :
                        LOG.fine("INQUIRY_COMPLETED");
                        break;
                    case DiscoveryListener.INQUIRY_TERMINATED :
                        LOG.fine("INQUIRY_TERMINATED");
                        break;
                    case DiscoveryListener.INQUIRY_ERROR :
                        LOG.fine("INQUIRY_ERROR");
                        break;
                    default :
                        LOG.fine("Unknown Response Code - " + respCode);
                        break;
                }
                }

                public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {
                        String rd = searchForServices.get(transID).getBluetoothAddress();
                        //searchForServices.remove(transID);
                switch (respCode) {
                        case DiscoveryListener.SERVICE_SEARCH_COMPLETED:
                                LOG.fine(rd + ": The service search completed normally");
                        break;
                        case DiscoveryListener.SERVICE_SEARCH_TERMINATED:
                                LOG.fine(rd + ": The service search request was cancelled by a call to DiscoveryAgent.cancelServiceSearch(int)");
                        break;
                        case DiscoveryListener.SERVICE_SEARCH_ERROR:
                                LOG.warning(rd + ": An error occurred while processing the request");
                        break;
                        case DiscoveryListener.SERVICE_SEARCH_NO_RECORDS:
                                LOG.info(rd + ": No records were found during the service search");
                        break;
                        case DiscoveryListener.SERVICE_SEARCH_DEVICE_NOT_REACHABLE:
                                LOG.warning(rd + ": The device specified in the search request could not be reached or the local device could not establish a connection to the remote device");
                        break;
                    default:
                        LOG.warning(rd + ": Unknown Response Code - " + respCode);
                        break;
                }
                        if (waitForDevices != null)
                                waitForDevices.countDown();
                }

                public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] srs) {
                        LOG.info("Services discovered in transaction " + transID + " : " + srs.length);
                        for (ServiceRecord sr : srs) {

LOG.info(sr.getConnectionURL(ServiceRecord.NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT, false));
                                servicesDiscovered.add(sr);
                        }
                }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                new Test().connect();
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the logs for this ... Also can you not pair before doing the service discovery ? (it is not necessary to pair for service discovery)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while connecting to a Bluetooth earpiece. Like you I was also searching for more than one service at a time and It always returned SERVICE_SEARCH_DEVICE_NOT_REACHABLE. So, I tried searching for only one service and it worked. So, try modifying your code as:

```
...
private static final UUID[] UUIDS = new UUID[] {new UUID(0x0003)}
```